# How to get all non-overlapping time intervals in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I would like to generate time intervals where there are no appointments between two times. More specifically, when someone is available during a certain interval.

For instance, if I check who is available between 1:30pm and 3:30pm, and Doctor1 has an appointment from 1:15pm-2:00pm and Doctor2 has an appointment from 2:30pm-3:30pm, the expected output should be: [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zZ6a.png)

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?
I have a table with Appointments (which includes AppointmentDate, StartTime, EndTime, DoctorName, etc.)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Isn't Doctor1 available 2:00 - 3:30 as well?

Comment: @Kosh Oh yes I believe it's in the expected output image, row 2

Comment: Right, sorry my blindness =))

Comment: Easy. Use PostgreSQL v14 with multiranges and subtraction.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have to check interval `[IntervalStart], [IntervalEnd]`. Then:

```
select
  Name,
  ifnull(
    (
      select EndTime from Appointments
      where
        Name = A.Name and
        EndTime between [IntervalStart] and A.StartTime
        order by EndTime desc
        limit 1
     ),
     [IntervalStart]
  ) as StartTime,
  StartTime as EndTime
from Appointments
where 
  StartTime between [IntervalStart] and [IntervalEnd]
union select
  Name,
  EndTime as StartTime,
  ifnull(
    (
      select StartTime from Appointments
      where
        Name = A.Name and
        StartTime between A.EndtTime and [IntervalEnd]
        order by StartTime
        limit 1
     ),
     [IntervalEnd]
  ) as EndTime
from Appointments
where
  EndTime between [IntervalStart] and [IntervalEnd]
order by Name, StartTime;
```